# node js asynchronous looping recursively issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
changeLog.find(filter).sort('-changeDate').exec(function(err, _doc) {
  if (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    return res.status(400).send({
      isSuccess: false,
      message: err,
      data: _doc
    });
  }
  var result = [];
  var match = (req.body.assetName).trim();
  if (match != "")
    GenerateHistoryForChangeLog(_doc, match, result);
  else
    PrepareResult(_doc, result);

  return res.status(200).send({
    isSuccess: true,
    message: err,
    data: result
  });
});

function GenerateHistoryForChangeLog(docs, match, result) {
  for (var counter = 0; counter < docs.length; counter++) {
    var doc = docs[counter];
    if (doc.afterImage.model) {
      if ((doc.afterImage.model.name)) {
        if ((doc.afterImage.model.name) == match) {
          if (doc.beforeImage.model) {
            var beforeModification = doc.beforeImage.model.assetClass;
            //  var newdocs=docs.slice(counter==0?0:(counter-1), doc.length);

            GenerateHistoryForChangeLog(docs, beforeModification, result);
            var object = new Object();
            ConstructPropertiesOfObject(doc, object);
            result.push(object);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In above code I am calling GenerateHistoryForChangeLog method recursively but it is giving max call stack reached.........how to solve this issue and there are chances that I will have thousands of docs to loop through and  I am doing synchronous looping also so it will block the other user call untill loop finishes. so I want to know what is best way to write this code in scalable way so that it doesn't suffer performance hit when no of doc increases and also doesn't give max call stack reached error. Any help appreciated

Comment: Have a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or any other framework that helps you prevent callback hell. Also, if you have thousands of docs, it's probably a better idea to not use a recursive loop.

Comment: Wait a minute - I just had another look.. Aren't you passing in the same `docs` variable to the recursive call that you got? Or is that a copy&paste error?

Comment: yes , I am passing same docs to recursive call

Comment: I believe the point there to be that generally when you have a recursive call on data, you are "changing" that data in some way on each iteration. You are just sending the same input over and over again. There also appears to be nothing aysnchronous here at all, unless you have omitted code ( which is not a wise idea when explaining a problem ).